# Does the kotlin REPL have code completion?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

I just opened `kotlinc` (which apparently defaults to `kotlin-jvm` ?)  and dropped in some `hello-world` type code:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) {
   val isAdult get() = age >= 20
}
```

Let's create an instance :

```
val p = Person("ab", 10)
```

Hopefully the `repl` will offer us the properties via `tab` key .. ?

```
p.<tab>
```

The `repl` **beeps** on each `tab` instead of offering the properties of that `Person` instance.  "Just in case" I `:quit` and opened `kotlinc-jvm` explicitly - and got the same behavior.    Is it to be believed that there were no `code completion` available?  Am I missing some option to starting `kotlinc` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: JetBrains has now released [ki](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/04/ki-the-next-interactive-shell-for-kotlin/), which supports auto completion (and more).

The kotlin repl currently does not support tab completion. See the official bug tracker for more details:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14177,
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23036

If you use IntelliJ, you may want to try out scratch files. They work well for small bits of code and support code completion.

Comment: ok - not the result I wanted to hear but let's award for being the messenger

Answer (score 2):

`Intellij` `Kotlin-REPL` does have code completion. It makes a ton of sense to use the IDE coming from the creators of the language `JetBrains`.

[image]

[image]