# How to enable Kotlin REPL autocomplete

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, autocomplete, read-eval-print-loop

I'm totally new to kotlin so I just installed IntelliJ on my pc for a course I'm taking.

Since I'm not new to programming using the autocomplete is merely to save a little time. I assumed it'd be enabled by default but it isn't the case.

After a little research I couldn't find any major answers whether the option was even there.
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61070133/6057960) about the topic I figured the feature does exists.

My question is, how do you enable the repl autocompletion feature? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.